# How to improve this tex files (frame for a cover page)

Tags: bookcover

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,enumerate,array,fancyhdr,enumitem,fancybox,graphicx,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{wrapfig}



\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 


\thispagestyle{empty}

%===============================


\usepackage{fancybox}
%======================================================== 
% languages & fonts===========================================

%%
%=========================================================



\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\def\z~#1~#2~#3~#4~#5~{
\node [rotate=#1]at (#2:#3){\pgfornament[width=#4cm,color=red]{#5}};
}
\def\s{%
\tikz{
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0)-|(0,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.14)-|(-0.14,4);
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0.48)-|(-3.2,1.2)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.48,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.38)-|(-3.08,1.1)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.38,4);
\draw[line width=6mm,color=white](135:2.8)+(-0.5,-0.5)--+(.5,.5);
\z~90~135~2.1~2.5~54~
\z~180~102~2.93~.8~55~
\z~-90~168~2.93~.8~56~
\z~0~94.5~5~1~67~
\z~90~178.5~5~1~67~
\z~90~91~16~15~83~
\z~90~92~7.5~6~85~
}
}
\def\r{%
\tikz{
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0)-|(0,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.14)-|(-0.14,4);
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0.48)-|(-3.2,1.2)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.48,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.38)-|(-3.08,1.1)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.38,4);
\draw[line width=6mm,color=white](135:2.8)+(-0.5,-0.5)--+(.5,.5);
\z~90~135~2.1~2.5~54~
\z~180~102~2.93~.8~55~
\z~-90~168~2.93~.8~56~
\z~0~94.5~5~1~67~
\z~90~178.5~5~1~67~
}
}
\def\t{
\tikz{\filldraw[rounded corners=5mm,draw=black!50!white,inner color=white,outer color=black](-4.5,-0.1)to[bend right=5](-2,0.5)--(2,.5)to[bend right=5,sharp corners](4.3,0)to[bend left=5](2,-.5)--(-2,-.5)to[bend left=5]cycle;
\filldraw[rounded corners=5mm,draw=red!50!white,inner color=black,outer color=black](4.5,-0.1)to[bend right=5](2,0.5)--(-2,.5)to[bend left=5,sharp corners](-4.3,0)to[bend left=5](-2,-.5)--(2,-.5)to[bend left=5]cycle;}
}

\parindent=0mm

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at ([shift={(-3.6,12.3)}]current page.south east){\s};
\node [rotate=180]at ([shift={(3.6,-12.3)}]current page.north west){\s};
\node [rotate=90]at ([shift={(-3.6,-3.6)}]current page.north east){\r};
\node [rotate=-90]at ([shift={(3.6,3.6)}]current page.south west){\r};
\node [yscale=0.6,scale=0.8]at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north){\t};
\node [yscale=0.6,scale=0.8]at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south){\t};
\node at ([shift={(0,-5.2cm)}]current page.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Improve" is somewhat vague, and opinion based, which doesn't make for a good TeX.SE question.  Is there a specific aspect of the file that you'd like to improve?

Comment: I want to draw a frame for a page but it gives me an error  at the first \node I don't know how to correct it  you can try to compile it  and you will see thank you for the help

Comment: @Teepeemm I edit the question I do a more precise tex files

Comment: @Vrouvrou your last line of code was missing the braces `\node at ([shift={(0,-5.2cm)}]current page.north){};` --additionally your corner offsets were off so I have corrected as per my perception -- I have a doubt which ornament you want in the `north` since you are not using the `def\z` so I have not fiddled with it -- I think you will be able to carry the solution from here

Comment: would you like to accept the answer if it met your requirement

Comment: @Vrouvrou would you like to accept the answer if it met your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,enumerate,array,fancyhdr,enumitem,fancybox,graphicx,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{wrapfig}



\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 


\thispagestyle{empty}

%===============================


\usepackage{fancybox}
%======================================================== 
% languages & fonts===========================================

%%
%=========================================================



\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\def\z~#1~#2~#3~#4~#5~{
\node [rotate=#1]at (#2:#3){\pgfornament[width=#4cm,color=red]{#5}};
}
\def\s{%
\tikz{
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0)-|(0,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.14)-|(-0.14,4);
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0.48)-|(-3.2,1.2)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.48,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.38)-|(-3.08,1.1)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.38,4);
\draw[line width=6mm,color=white](135:2.8)+(-0.5,-0.5)--+(.5,.5);
% \z~90~135~2.1~2.5~54~
% \z~180~102~2.93~.8~55~
% \z~-90~168~2.93~.8~56~
% \z~0~94.5~5~1~67~
% \z~90~178.5~5~1~67~
% \z~90~91~16~15~83~
% \z~90~92~7.5~6~85~
}
}
\def\r{%
\tikz{
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0)-|(0,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.14)-|(-0.14,4);
\draw [line width=2pt](-4,0.48)-|(-3.2,1.2)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.48,4);
\draw [line width=1pt](-4,0.38)-|(-3.08,1.1)arc(-90:0:1)arc(-90:0:1)-|(-0.38,4);
\draw[line width=6mm,color=white](135:2.8)+(-0.5,-0.5)--+(.5,.5);
% \z~90~135~2.1~2.5~54~
% \z~180~102~2.93~.8~55~
% \z~-90~168~2.93~.8~56~
% \z~0~94.5~5~1~67~
% \z~90~178.5~5~1~67~
}
}
\def\t{
\tikz{\filldraw[rounded corners=5mm,draw=black!50!white,inner color=white,outer color=black]
              (-4.5,-0.1)to[bend right=5](-2,0.5)--(2,.5)to[bend right=5,sharp corners](4.3,0)to[bend left=5](2,-.5)--(-2,-.5)to[bend left=5]cycle;
\filldraw[rounded corners=5mm,draw=red!50!white,inner color=black,outer color=black]
              (4.5,-0.1)to[bend right=5](2,0.5)--(-2,.5)to[bend left=5,sharp corners](-4.3,0)to[bend left=5](-2,-.5)--(2,-.5)to[bend left=5]cycle;}
}

% \parindent=0mm

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at ([shift={(-3,3)}]current page.south east){\s};
\node [rotate=180]at ([shift={(3,-3)}]current page.north west){\s};
\node [rotate=90]at ([shift={(-3,-3)}]current page.north east){\r};
\node [rotate=-90]at ([shift={(3,3)}]current page.south west){\r};
\node [yscale=0.6,scale=0.8]at ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north){\t};
\node [yscale=0.6,scale=0.8]at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south){\t};
\node at ([shift={(0,-5.2cm)}]current page.north){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please can you give me your email address I need help with my document